# Can i still have bitcode disabled for iOS if one or more libraries has bitcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

Can I still build and publish an iOS application which has bitcode disabled, even if I have one or more libraries which have bitcode?

Not all my libraries I depend on support bitcode yet. But I have read on certain forums that you cannot have bitcode disabled for your iOS target if some of your libraries have bitcode.

What if I am targeting both iOS and watchOS? I understand that you can selectively enable bitcode for watchOS (in fact it's required) and disable for the iOS target, but what about in the case of a mix of libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, yes, you can have a mix of Bitcode settings among multiple libraries that you use and have your app successfully published.

There is a master switch for enabling Bitcode under **My Apps > Pricing and Availability > Bitcode Auto-Recompilation** in iTunes Connect that is independent of your project settings. If this is disabled, Bitcode will not be used at all.

I have successfully published my latest iOS app having **Enable Bitcode** set to **No** in the Build Settings for my target while also having **Enable Bitcode** set to **Yes** in the Pods used in my project.

Comment: Daniel, Is this still the case that you can submit applications with Enable Bitcode set to No? I have read some places that apps without bitcode enabled are being rejected but I think that it is largely coming from strict interpretations of the xcode 7.0 release notes.

Comment: @Matt Bitcode is currently optional for iOS apps according to the App Distribution Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html). If it were Apple's policy to require Bitcode than they could reject the binary on upload. Bitcode will probably be mandatory for iOS in the future so it's a good idea to move toward it.